# How to add large number of pages to a content type?

Tags: nodes

I created a content type "cities", with
Fields: Title, body, location(text field)

I would like to create about 200 pages for this content type.

I can create manually one by one. It will take a lot of time to do that. Is there faster way I can add the pages by using some bulk load methods?

Comment: You can look into the Feeds (Drupal 7 only) or Migrate (Drupal 7 & 8) modules to import data from a csv.

Comment: any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, and its `devel_generate` submodule.

Using this submodule, you can perfectly create 200 nodes (with randomly generated content) of any content type.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the nodes from a php array:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;


    $values = [
      'type' => 'my_content_type',
      'title' => 'test title',
      'body' => [
        [
          'value' => 'test body',
          'summary' => '',
          'format' => 'filtered_html',
        ],
      ],
      'field_location' => 'test locatation',
      'status' => NodeInterface::PUBLISHED,
    ];

    $node = Node::create($values);
    $node->save();
```